# Is this property of the Bell's number evident?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $B(n)$ denote the Bell's number which is the number of the equivalence relation which can be defined on a set of cardinality $n$.

While I was trying to solve a problem, I reached another result;

$$B(p^k)\equiv k+1 \ mod \ p$$

Is this result evident or trivial ? Any comments and remark are welcome.

**Note:** My field is not Number theory, that is why I am not famialiar with the tools and result in number theory. If this question is something trivial, please excuse me.

Comment: It is well-known and there are more general results for arbitrary polynomials of a prime variable $p$ instead of $p^k$. The rhs depends on a polynomial only, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you please give some reference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the well-known Touchard's congruence ([here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0696) for a random reference). Following your notation, the congruence is:

$$B(n+p^k)\equiv kB(n)+B(n+1) \mod \ p$$

Taking $n=0$:

$$B(p^k)\equiv kB(0)+B(1) \mod \ p$$

And since $B(0)=B(1)=1$,

$$B(p^k)\equiv k+1 \mod \ p$$

Comment: See e.g. that paper for generalizations (and the references within):
http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bbms/1102714984

Comment: Another reference is http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/19-2/gessel.pdf.